# Redis persistence issue

Tags: database, node.js, redis, persistence

I have only one key in Redis database which I use much frequently in my Node.js application. This key is incremented every time I access it. My issue is that I don't want to miss a value even though a system crashes or anything happen unexpectedly. Because recently I noticed that my system crashed and key value was reset to zero or sometimes it resets to any older values.

So far I tried using RDB and AOF to save every write to the disk.
For RDB I used config as below:

> save 0 1

I understand that it will write snapshot after every change in the key.

For AOF I tried as:

> appendfsync always

After setting this config I try to shutdown Redis as `redis-server shutdown nosave`

Then I start Redis but see the that latest values are not stored.

Comment: You will have to set the `appendonly yes` config. According to this http://redis.io/topics/persistence#append-only-file

Comment: I have set that too, I just didn't write it above. Well just let me know if my test case I am doing is correct or wrong.

Comment: Can you set to every second? So `save 1 1` as per the documentation indicated _The suggested (and default) policy is to fsync every second. It is both very fast and pretty safe. The always policy is very slow in practice (although it was improved in Redis 2.0) – there is no way to make fsync faster than it is._

Comment: I have tried that too but latest values are not saved to the disk.

Comment: do you mind stating the exact process on how the key is being accessed and what do you use to increment it? I am guessing that persistence has nothing to do with the latest values not being saved. It might be the way you increment the value. You can monitor the activity from the terminal by using `MONITOR` to determine if the values were really saved to the key and next is when you assume that it is definitely the persistence issue. Please read this when shutting down server http://redis.io/commands/shutdown#save-and-nosave-modifiers

Comment: I am using incr to increment key value. Every time my application server receives any request first thing its does is, it goes to redis to get the get the value and increment it. This value is stored in some other database which should never be repeated. We can't think of loosing even a single value due to system crash or restart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95648/discussion-between-vincent-and-viddesh).

Comment: I just rebooted my server and my key value was reset to zero.